# can we inherit base class constructor in java

Tags: java

Let say I have a class:

```
class A {
    A() {
        System.out.print("constructor of A class");
    }
}

class B extends A {

    A() {
        // why i am not override super class constructor?
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {

    }
}
```

Why I am not able to override super class constructor?

Comment: We don't inherit constructors in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java Constructors cannot be overridden or inherited. They cannot be called virtually. What can be done is calling super class constructor from child class constructor using `super()`

Answer (score 0):

In java constructor is not inherited.

Refer this question:
[Why constructors can not be inherited in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147768/why-constructors-can-not-be-inherited-in-java)

Comment: Don't give link to the question in answer if your are not going to add some new information , mark duplicate instead !!