# Can't change properties in UILabel subclass

Tags: swift, uikit, uilabel

I have a bunch of same labels and created UILabel subclass to customise them. But changes made in CustomizedLabel are not applied to labels in view controller. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class CustomizedLabel: UILabel {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit(){
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        textColor = UIColor.green
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
    
}
```

And view:

```
import UIKit

class StatiscticsScreenViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var threeSymbTimeRecordLabel: CustomizedLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fourSymbTimeRecordLabel: CustomizedLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fiveSymbTimeRecordLabel: CustomizedLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sixSymbTimeRecordLabel: CustomizedLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sevenSymbTimeRecordLabel: CustomizedLabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var ThreeSymbMovesRecordLabel: CustomizedLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var FourSymbMovesRecordLabel: CustomizedLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var FiveSymbMovesRecordLabel: CustomizedLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var SixSymbMovesRecordLabel: CustomizedLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var SevenSymbMovesRecordLabel: CustomizedLabel!
    
    ...
```

Unfortunately for now I don't have possibility for voting for comment but first comment from Cristik actually helped me. I just forgot to change class on Storybord

Comment: Are the views defined as `CustomizedLabel` in the storyboard/xib?

Comment: first, make sure commonInit() method is running

Comment: make sure of you'd apply those visual changes (`commonInit()`) at the right point of the view lifecycle, eg. when it has a `superview` or when the layout needs to be updated (ie. `layoutSubviews()`).

Comment: OMG ))) many thanks @Cristik  ))))

Comment: @Ryan110 thanks for reply. I just forgot to change class to created subclass on storyboard.

Comment: @harasym in that case I think you can delete the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

IBOutlet are not created via the init.
To Configure your custom label, make changes in awakeFromNib method and not in the init of UILabel class.

Comment: What do you mean they are not created? `required init?(coder aDecoder:` this init gets called when the view unarchived from `nib/xib` file file.

Answer (score -1):

you are creating your labels from storyboard, not programmatically. so, you should try this one

```
import UIKit

class CustomizedLabel: UILabel {

    
    func commonInit(){
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        textColor = UIColor.green
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonInit()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386339/what-exactly-is-init-coder-adecoder/38386580