# Creating empty child class constructor

Tags: java, class, inheritance, constructor

```
public class Monitor extends Peripheral {
    public Monitor(){
        super();
    }
    public Monitor (String name,String maker, int age, int price,String type,int size,String res,String ports){
        super(name,maker,age,price);
        this.type = typel
        this.size = size;
        this.res = res;
        this.ports = ports;
    }
}
```

This is the the child class.I want to make it so that I can create a monitor object without giving it any parameters. These are the classes of its parents:

```
public class Product {
    protected String name, maker;
    protected int age,price;
    public Product(){}
    public Product(String name,String maker, int age, int price){
        this.name = name;
        this.maker = maker;
        this.age = age;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
public class Peripheral extends Product {
    //basically nothing here
    private static double discount = 0;
    public static void setDiscount(double disc){
        discount = disc;
    }
    public static double getDiscount(){
        return discount;
    }
}
```

The compiler says:error: constructor Peripheral in class Peripheral cannot be aplied to given types;
                  super();
required: String,String,int,int
found: no arguments

Comment: `super(...)` in `Monitor` delegates call to `Peripheral` constructor which doesn't have such signature. Perhaps, you need to define it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor with Peripheral parametars!

```
Peripheral(String name, String maker, int age, int price)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Peripheral` [does not inherit constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147768/why-constructors-can-not-be-inherited-in-java) from `Product`, you need to declare it explictly:

```
public class Peripheral extends Product {

    public Peripheral(String name,String maker, int age, int price) {
        super(name,maker,age,price);
    } 

    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you have a typo in here:

```
public Monitor (String name,String maker, int age, int price,String type,int 
size,String res,String ports){
    super(name,maker,age,price);
    this.type = typel <--- here(nasty semi-colons)
```

I think you will forcefully have to create a product object before your monitor object as you will be missing those super parameters which your monitor is trying to get.

A work around is, you might want to create another constructor that doesn't have the super(params); so that way it will get rid of that error you are getting.

so instead of your constructor, you should do something like this:

```
public Monitor (String type,int size,String res,String ports){
    this.type = type;
    this.size = size;
    this.res = res;
    this.ports = ports;
}
```

hope this solves your issue!

Comment: The issue here is that I want to create an empty Monitor object (taking no parameters) but I don't seem to be able to becuase something is up with the super(). Thanks anyway.

Comment: where exactly do you want to create it?