# Does Java RuntimeException support constructor inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have a class derived from `RuntimeException` and a function as below.

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {
  // No contructor implemented;
  // This class inherits the constructors from its parent;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String msg = "msg";
  MyException baseException = new MyException(); // No compiling error
  MyException baseException2 = new MyException(msg); // Compiling error: Expected 0 arguments but found 1
}
```

It looks like `MyException` inherits the `default constructor` from `RuntimeException`,
but it does **not** inherit the `1-arg constructor RuntimeException(String message)`.

Is this expected? Why is Java designed like this?

I noticed that the similar question was discussed at [Java Constructor Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644317/java-constructor-inheritance).
**That link does not answer my question since:**
They said Java does not support constructor inheritance, but based on my above observation, Java does support the inheritance of the default constructor,
but it does not support the 1-arg constructor. Thus I am not sure of the correctness of the answers in that link.

@Slaw gave an excellent answer: the default constructor is not from inheritance -- it is added by the compiler; Also how the default constructor and other constructors are invoked; In what situation, the compile will fail. I have upvoted that answer.

Comment: Your question is answered by David Santamaria's answer in the question you linked.

Comment: *Nothing* in Java 'supports constructor inheritance'. Constructors are not inherited. `MyException` does not *have* a 1-argument constructor. No other explanation required.

Comment: The no-argument constructor of `RuntimeException` is not inherited. You haven't given `MyException` a constructor, and so a default one is implicitly added by the compiler. That default constructor invokes the superclass's _no-argument_ constructor (as all constructors implicitly try to do when there's no explicit call to `super(...)` or `this(...)`). If such a constructor does not exist or is not visible, then the subclass fails to compile.

Comment: Regarding "Why is Java designed like this?": see [Why are constructors not inherited in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147768/why-are-constructors-not-inherited-in-java)

Comment: If I explicitly define a constructor, say a 1-arg constructor, will the compiler still add the default one? (It seems not from what I observed.)

Comment: The default constructor is only added by the compiler if no other constructor is explicitly defined. And if you give `MyException` a one-argument constructor, say for the message argument, and you want it to behave like the equivalent constructor of `RuntimeException`, its implementation would look like: `public MyException(String msg) { super(msg); }`.