# Can move constructor take arguments other than the class itself?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, move-semantics, move-constructor

Basically, the argument of the move constructor is the class itself.

However, if I want to construct an object of the class from a lvalue without copy operation can I do like this?

```
class A{
   A(const LargeDataType& inData):data(inData) {} // constructor 1
   A(LargeDataType&& inData):data(std::move(inData)) {} // constructor 2
   private:
        LargeDataType data;
};
```

To use it:

Method 1:

```
LargeDataType outData = 100;
A objA(std::move(outData)); // call constructor 2
```

Method 2 (If constructor 2 was not implemented):

```
LargeDataType outData = 100;
A objA(std::move(outData)); // call constructor 1
```

In this way, there is no copy operation when constructing the objA. My questions are:

1. Is this legal to create a move constructor like this?
2. This is more efficient than traditional constructor because no copy needed during objA creation?
3. Whether method 2 could be better and has the same efficiency as the method 1?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You aren't avoiding any copies with these shenanigans, because "moving" and `int` is the same as copying it.

Comment: `int` does not have a move constructor or any move operations, so this all just becomes copies...

Comment: For `int`, it is not really useful, but might be useful for `std::string` or `std::vector` for example.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, this is just an example, I want to use this for more complicated data types

Comment: You can certainly write a constructor like that, and doing so can even have benefits. But it is not a move constructor.

Comment: @lightrek Well, you should try not to simplify away things that actually matter.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley will this kind of rvalue reference constructor more efficient than lvalue reference constructor?

Comment: If the type being passed in is cheaper to move than it is to copy, yes.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724657/why-do-we-copy-then-move

Comment: thanks a lot@BenjaminLindley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is not a move constructor. It is just a constructor that takes rvalue references as arguments. The are perfectly fine constructors but they are not move constructors.

From the C++11 Standard (12.8/3):

> A non-template constructor for class `X` is a move constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&&`, `const X&&`, `volatile X&&`, or `const volatile X&&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6).

Only

```
A(A&& a) { ... }
A(const A&& a) { ... }
A(volatile A&& a) { ... }
A(volatile const A&& a) { ... }
```

maybe called move constructors.

If you have parameters with default values in addition to the above, they also qualify as move constructors. E.g.

```
A(A&& a, T arg = {}) { ... }
```

Comment: A move constructor can have more signatures than the one in your example.

Comment: `A(const A&&)` would also be a move constructor ;-)

Comment: Even `A(volatile A&&)`

Comment: Still not complete :) `A(A&&, T = {})` and so on would also be move constructors. The additional parameters must all have default arguments.

Comment: As a purely colloquial matter, sometimes people call `Foo(Bar&&);` a "converting move constructor". Language-lawyers will undoubtedly point out that that terminology doesn't make much sense.