# using Base::Base; in Derived class, what does that do exactly?

Tags: c++, c++14

In the below code, what does `using Base::Base;` do exactly? I suspect it "copies" all constructors verbatim, since I get access to `Derived(std::string)` by doing it, but is that the only effect of the statement? I originally found the statement in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3120537/5377635 and are unsuccessful in locating its description in the cpp reference.

```
class Base {
    Base(std::string name);
};

class Derived : public Base {
    using Base::Base; // <<----------
};
```

Comment: Yes, this is called "inheriting constructors". It performs a certain amount of magic when default arguments are present on a base constructor.

Comment: Thank you! The term inheriting constructors was enough for me to find it at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration Please leave an answer for me to close.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't quite feel enough for an answer. Maybe you can find a full explanation of Stack Overflow and we can mark this question as a duplicate?

Comment: Sure thing, I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979194/what-is-constructor-inheritance but not enough rep to mark duplicates yet.