# How to initialize a custom container with a multi-dimensional initializer list?

Tags: c++, stdmap, initializer-list

I'm currently working on a custom wrapper for the `std::map` type with additional methods like `ContainsValue()`. But since I try to make it as compatible with std::map as possible, I'd like to know if it's possible to initialize it with a "multi-dimensional initializer list".

My custom map type is defined like this:

```
template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
class CustomMap {
private:
  std::map<TKey, TValue> mapContent;

public:
  // Some interaction methods here

  void operator=(/* initialization type here */) {
    /* initialization here */
  }
}
```

And I'm talking about an initializer list like this:

```
CustomMap<uint64_t, std::string> test = {
  { 0xFF, "MaxByte" },
  { 0xFFFF, "MaxWord" },
  { 0xFFFFFFFF, "MaxDWord" },
  { 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, "MaxQWord" }
};
```

Notice that there's **no casting of any type** in the initialization. It's all happening automatically; just as with the original `std::map` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, make a constructor taking `std::initializer_list<value_type>` like `std::map` has: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map

Or forward all constructors: [Forwarding all constructors in C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119929/forwarding-all-constructors-in-c0x)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really get it. Doesn't std::initializer_list<> just contain one single type? Then how exactly would I do this? To be honest, I don't even know how this works with std::map.

Comment: @RobinLe you can use `using value_type = std::pair<TKey, TValue>` in your container (just like it's done in `std::map`). Afterwards, your `std::initializer_list<value_type>` will actually take objects of the same type which is a pair of a key and a value.

Comment: @passing_through Ah, alright, Thank you very much! :)